# List of webelements getting cleared during my test run?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm trying to compare two different tables using the method called `VerifyOrderSummary` located at the end of the `main` method below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();   

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Item testItem = Item.WRENCH;

    driver.get("http://test.url/WebOrderScreen");
    AddItem(testItem);
    ChangeItemQuantity(testItem, 3);

    WebElement shoppingCartListContents = driver.findElement(By.id("shopping-cart")).findElement(By.xpath(".//tbody[@class='nx-list-contents']"));
    List<WebElement> shoppingCartRows = shoppingCartListContents.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    System.out.println(shoppingCartRows.size());
    System.out.println(shoppingCartRows.get(0).getText());

    ClickWorkflowButton(Button.PAYMENTINFORMATION);

    WebElement orderSummaryListContents = driver.findElement(By.id("order-summary")).findElement(By.xpath(".//tbody[@class='nx-list-contents']"));
    List<WebElement> orderSummaryRows = orderSummaryListContents.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    VerifyOrderSummary(shoppingCartRows, orderSummaryRows);


}
```

The issue i am seeing is that when i print out the first row of `shoppingRowCartsRows` in the main method, it prints out correctly.

but within the VerifyOrderSummary method, it prints out a blank line:

```
 public static void VerifyOrderSummary(List<WebElement> shoppingCartRows, List<WebElement> orderSummaryRows) {      

    //given the shopping cart rows and order summary rows, compare the two

    for(int i = 0; i < shoppingCartRows.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println("shopping cart row: "+shoppingCartRows.get(i).getText());
        System.out.println("order summary row: "+orderSummaryRows.get(i).getText());


        //          Assert.assertEquals(shoppingCartRows.get(i).getText(), orderSummaryRows.get(i).getText());

        //System.out.println(models.get(i).getName());

    }
```

Can anyone tell me why that is happening? I'm completely lost at the moment.

Comment: Which line is printed blank?

Comment: I would be interested if ClickWorkflowButton(Button.PAYMENTINFORMATION); navigates away from the page you collected your rows from. My initial guess is that the elements you found might have gone stale before you tried to use them a second time.

Comment: I hope when navigate to payment info, the items in the shopping cart is removed from session of your application. Please can you check the cookie variables in the shopping cart page as well as in the order review page.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to use `WebElement` objects as the carriers of some long-life information. They might change depending on the changes of your page. Instead I would recommend to have the following approach:

1. You have `WebElement` list that you have just populated somehow:

   ```
   List<WebElement> weList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//some-x-path"));
   ```
2. Then you should create a list holding the types of valuable parts of your Webelements. For text it would look like:

   2.1. **For Java 8:**

   **either**

   ```
   List<String> weText = new ArrayList<>();
   weList.forEach(webElement -> {weText.add(webElement.getText());});
   ```

   **or**

   ```
   List<String> weText  = weList.stream().map(webElement -> webElement.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

   2.2. **For pre-8 Java:**

   ```
   List<String> weText = new ArrayList<>();
   for(WebElement webElement: weList){
       weText.add(webElement.getText());
   }
   ```

Now you can preserve the values for further comparison.